# Ternary operator truthy or falsy on v-bind vuejs

Tags: vuejs2

I'm in a project using VueJS 2
I want to define a certain value with a v-bind using a ternary operator. My value is either truthy (an object) or falsy (undefined)

Here is the code :

```js
<b-icon
    class="select-icon"
    pack="fas"
    :icon="selectedUsers[user.objectID] ? 'circle' : 'check-circle'"
    size="is-medium"
    type="is-primary"
/>
```

This is to define which icon should appear. With a direct true or false it work, but not with truthy or falsy. Is there a way to bypass that ?

I tried transforming it to a Boolean with `!!selectedUsers[user.objectID])`
and loggin it with :
`console.log(!!this.selectedUsers[user.objectID]);`

but not working

Here is the console.log() :
[image]

EDIT : here is the code that should mutate my selectedUsers, i think this is where i'm doing something wrong, i'll check if the render is triggered or not

```
methods: {
    selectUser(user) {
      console.log(user);
      if (this.selectedUsers[user.objectID]) {
        delete this.selectedUsers[user.objectID];
      } else {
        this.selectedUsers[user.objectID] = user;
      }
      console.log('this.selectedUsers: ', this.selectedUsers);
      console.log(!!this.selectedUsers[user.objectID]);
    },
  },
```

Comment: Can you add more details like what error you get or what value `icon` prop gets?

Comment: What did you get when you console logged it ?

Comment: console.log() give either true or false when i pass with a Boolean, and if not bool it gives an object or undefined

and icon is always 'check-circle'

Comment: Does  `:icon="typeof selectedUsers[user.objectID] == 'object' ? 'circle' : 'check-circle'"` work for you?

Comment: it comes from the render not trigerred (updated)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some search, it appears that nested object not declared into the `data` element of VueJS will not be watch, so if changed will not trigger rendering.

For them to be reactive, we have to set or delete them with specific vue methods :

```
 methods: {
    selectUser(user) {
      if (this.selectedUsers[user.objectID]) {
        this.$delete(this.selectedUsers, user.objectID);
      } else {
        this.$set(this.selectedUsers, user.objectID, user);
      }
    },
```

With this code the rendering is triggered. I was not aware of this specificity.

To read more on this, [check this official documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats)

Answer (score 0):

Mutation should be last approach, it makes mess when series of calling functions happenend.

Why not you just use computed?

From the code, it seems that you want to achieve value 'circle' OR 'check-circle'

```
  <b-icon
    class="select-icon"
    pack="fas"
    v-bind:icon="check"
    size="is-medium"
    type="is-primary"
  />

  computed: {
      check(){
         return selectedUsers[user.objectID] ? 'circle' : 'check-circle';
      }

  }
```

I hope I understand what you're trying to achieve. If not, please give some more references. I will try my best to solve it.